# how to subtract time data type based on condition in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data frame like this:

```
   cust_id  amount                 time city
0        1    5000  2016-06-19T09:04:13   kc
1        2    5000  2016-06-19T09:04:13   ca
2        3    4000  2016-06-19T09:04:13   wd
3        1    5000  2016-06-19T9:40:13    kc
4        1    5000  2016-06-19T10:20:13   kc
5        2    5000  2016-06-19T09:50:13   ca
```

this code:

```
import pandas as pd

mydic = {'cust_id': [1,2,3,1,1,2],'amount':[5000, 5000, 4000, 5000, 5000, 5000], 'time':['2016-06-19T09:04:13', '2016-06-19T09:04:13', '2016-06-19T09:04:13',
                                                                                   '2016-06-19T9:40:13', '2016-06-19T10:20:13', '2016-06-19T09:50:13'],
         'city':['kc', 'ca', 'wd', 'kc', 'kc', 'ca']}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydic)
```

I want to select duplicated rows based on `cust_id, amount, city` and `time`. however, time has a exception: if I found duplicated rows with those three column then I need to see if their timing has less than one hour or not. if the difference between the time was less than one hour in the same date i will mark it as duplicate otherwise it is not duplicated.

For example, based on the example above these are duplicate:

```
   cust_id  amount                 time city
3        1    5000  2016-06-19T9:40:13   kc
5        2    5000  2016-06-19T09:50:13  ca
```

So far I have done this:

```
print(df[df.duplicated(['cust_id', 'amount', 'city'])])
```

But I do not know how can I subtract certain rows in time column(data type is datetime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
# find dups and create a copy
dup = df[df.duplicated(['cust_id', 'amount', 'city'], keep=False)].copy()

# add date column because you will prob want to group on date as well in a larger dataset
dup['date'] = dup['time'].dt.date

# groupby and calc the diff between the groups from the first timestamp when sorted
dup['diff'] = dup.sort_values('time').groupby(['cust_id', 'amount', 'city', 'date'])['time'].apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0])

# filter dataframe where the diff is less than 1 hour and does not equal 0
dup[(dup['diff'] < pd.Timedelta('1 hour')) & (dup['diff'] != pd.Timedelta('0 hour'))]
```

out:

```
   cust_id  amount                time city        date     diff
3        1    5000 2016-06-19 09:40:13   kc  2016-06-19 00:36:00
5        2    5000 2016-06-19 09:50:13   ca  2016-06-19 00:46:00
```

It should be a little faster to use `transform` rather than `apply`

```
# data
mydic = {'cust_id': [1,2,3,1,1,2],'amount':[5000, 5000, 4000, 5000, 5000, 5000], 'time':['2016-06-19T09:04:13', '2016-06-19T09:04:13', '2016-06-19T09:04:13',
                                                                                   '2016-06-19T9:40:13', '2016-06-19T10:20:13', '2016-06-19T09:50:13'],
         'city':['kc', 'ca', 'wd', 'kc', 'kc', 'ca']}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydic)

# convert to datetime
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# create date column
df['date'] = df['time'].dt.date

# sort values
df = df.sort_values('time')
```

The updated diff calc

```
# groupby and transform then subtract (without using apply)
df['diff'] = df['time'] - df.groupby(['cust_id', 'amount', 'city', 'date'])['time'].transform('first')

# filter dataframe where the diff is less than 1 hour and does not equal 0
df[(df['diff'] < pd.Timedelta('1 hour')) & (df['diff'] != pd.Timedelta('0 hour'))]
```

You can change the last line of code to the following if you want the duplicates removed from the original df:

```
df[~((df['diff'] < pd.Timedelta('1 hour')) & (df['diff'] != pd.Timedelta('0 hour')))]

   cust_id  amount                time city        date     diff
0        1    5000 2016-06-19 09:04:13   kc  2016-06-19 00:00:00
1        2    5000 2016-06-19 09:04:13   ca  2016-06-19 00:00:00
2        3    4000 2016-06-19 09:04:13   wd  2016-06-19 00:00:00
4        1    5000 2016-06-19 10:20:13   kc  2016-06-19 01:16:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is exactly what I was looking for. do you think I can achieve this even with better performance? my data is huge so I need the most efficient way to extract these duplicates. is it doable with `pd.merge_asof`?

Comment: The update should be a little faster as I removed the `duplicated` function and am now using `transform` instead of `apply` This assumes you are ok modifying the original dataframe i.e. adding columns and sorting

Comment: Thank you so much for the updated case. Actually when I try to apply this code on the real data set, I receive this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` in this line `dup['diff'] = ` in both codes. do you have any idea what could be the root of this error?

Comment: Yes, your time column is actually a string rather than a datetime object. Do `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])` first

Comment: I actually did that, in case I convert using `df['transactionDateTime'].dt.date`, this arises `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values` in the conversion line. When I convert using this `pd.DatetimeIndex(df['transactionDateTime']).date` this raises `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: join me in the chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201485/helping-sariii